# Combination of $4$ digit numbers not divisible by $5$

Tags: permutations

The number of $4$ digit numbers which are not divisible by $5$ that can be formed using the digits $(0,2,4,5)$ if digits are not repeated is?

Comment: The last digit can take any one of $2$ values. For each choice, the first digit can take on any one of $2$ values. And the remaining two digits can be placed in the remaining two slots in $2$ ways, for a total of $(2)(2)(2)$.

Comment: What have you try? Specifically, have you considering listing out all the possibilities (there are not many), to see if you can discover any pattern?

Answer (score 3):

There are 12 such numbers

$0254$$\hspace{0.9cm}$
$0524$$\hspace{0.9cm}$
$2054$$\hspace{0.9cm}$
$2504$$\hspace{0.9cm}$

$5024$$\hspace{0.9cm}$
$5204$$\hspace{0.9cm}$
$0452$$\hspace{0.9cm}$
$0542$

$4052$$\hspace{0.9cm}$
$4502$$\hspace{0.9cm}$
$5042$$\hspace{0.9cm}$
$5402$

4 are 3 digit numbers$\hspace{0.9cm}$ $0254$$\hspace{0.9cm}$$0524$$\hspace{0.9cm}$$0452$$\hspace{0.9cm}$$0542$

So the answer is 8

Comment: $4$ of them are $3$-digit numbers!!!

Comment: So after you've corrected yourself, please undo the down-vote you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

Well:

- It cannot start with $0$ (because it must be a $4$-digit number)
- It cannot end with $0$ or $5$ (because it must not be divisible by $5$)

This leaves you with only $8$ options:

- $2054$
- $2504$
- $4052$
- $4502$
- $5024$
- $5042$
- $5204$
- $5402$

Comment: @ Barak: Ain't you missing two combinations
5024 & 5042
So total combinations will be 8??

Comment: @Vikas: Ain't got nothing else to say besides thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

$$4!-(3!+3!+3!)+2!=8$$
$4!$ for all permutations,

$3!$ for the numbers starting with $0$, ending on $0$ and ending on $5$ respectively,

$2!$ for the numbers starting with $0$ and ending on $5$.